# Install and run a package inside a github action services

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

Is there a way to install and run a package inside a github services container? For instance:

```yaml
name: test

build:
  remote_server:
    name: ${{ matrix.os }} - Python v${{ matrix.python-version }}
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    services:
      server:
        image: ubuntu-latest
        # How to install a python package here?

    steps:
      - name: "Install and run client package"
        run: |
          # commands to install the client package
          # command to execute the client. Client should connect to the server

``
```

Comment: Any reason why you're using a container service approach over a `runs_on: ubuntu-latest`?

Comment: No particular reason. It was just an example. Ideally I'd like to test multple combinations os client/host operating systems.

Comment: Have you tried in the `steps` to have a `run | pip install ....`? Note: Not sure if `ubuntu-latest` have `python` and `pip` so you might need to `apt update && apt install python pip`